# Does the path matter for push ids?

Tags: firebase

I've been creating a consumer who "grants" ids to clients when they perform certain tasks. It occurred to me at some point that it might be entirely superfluous to worry about the path before I do a `.push().name()` to create new ids.

Does it matter what path I run the .push().name() on to create a unique ID? Does Firebase generate the IDs entirely based on timestamp, without regard to the path the ID will be assigned to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, push() ids are generated based on timestamps (along with some randomness). The path on which the id is being pushed is not used as part of the id.